# Parse WebClient response to Custom error Object?

Tags: java, cxf

I have this code, I use cxf WebClient:

```
WebClient client = someClient.reset();
Response response = client.post(bodyRequest);
```

If status code in response turns into 200 I can parse it into something like this:

```
CustomResponse customResponse = response.readEntity(CustomResponse.class);
```

And that's ok, but if status code turns to be 400 or another, response entity seems to be null, so I can't find a way to parse it into an object ResponseCodeError, like this:

```
ResponseCodeError responseError= response.readEntity(ResponseCodeError.class);
```

This will fail.

Is there a way to use cxf and parse error into Custom error class?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain, that with every erroneous response, you retrieve the exact same object structure, so it could be parsed to the given class? If you're certain, that it's the case, you could try reading the response to String and then parsing it separately from XML or JSON to an actual object, depending on the type of payload, that you receive

Comment: I'm sure about that, the problem is that when I inspect the response with debug, if status code is different from 200, there's no object at all. It's like, depending on the status code there's body or not, no matter if I send a body error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status using

```
int code = response.getStatus();
```

then you check for a code of 200 to parse the entity or throw the respective error for other codes like 400.

Comment: Thanks, but I need something else. I have to be able to get the response entity and parse it into a Custom error class. But when code status is not 200, entity seems to be null, so I can't parse it.

Comment: I think that you can't have an entity with every error, for example, if you timeout because of network problems or get 404 for incorrect spelling, the server can't send you a custom error, so you have to use the codes to build your own errors. But I don't have much experience with Apache Cxf, maybe it is possible to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but code status is just an example. The most important thing for me here is to be able to get a body(Custom class for that) when code is not 200.